# How can I scale/zoom in and out the widgets with only one finger using matrix gesture detector?

Tags: matrix, flutter, flutter-layout, scaling, gesturedetector

I am trying to scaling/zooming the widgets by tapping and dragging from certain points of widgets by only one finger using matrix gesture detector.With two finger it is working but i need it done with one finger.How can I implement it?  My code is:

```
class MyTransformWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 final Widget transformWidget;
 MyTransformWidget({this.transformWidget});
 @override
 _MyTransformWidgetState createState() => _MyTransformWidgetState();
}

class _MyTransformWidgetState extends State<MyTransformWidget> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier = ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());
   return MatrixGestureDetector(
     onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
       notifier.value = m;
     },
     child: AnimatedBuilder(
       animation: notifier,
       child: widget.transformWidget,
       builder: (ctx, child) {
         return Transform(transform: notifier.value, child: child);
       },
     ),
     shouldRotate: false,
     shouldScale: true,
     shouldTranslate: false,
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you experimented with a GestureDetector and onDoubleTap?

Comment: @JoãoSoares no haven't test it yet.I don't want it double tap

Comment: How do you want Flutter to detect the users intentions to differentiate between zooming and dragging, if can only use one finger?

Comment: I want only zooming with one finger tapped and dragged using matrix gesture detector instead of pinching

Comment: Your question is still not clear enough. You want users to be able to, for example, zoom out by dragging up and zoom in by dragging down?

Comment: @JoãoSoares yes you got it now

Comment: That is really unintuitive to use and bad UX. It would probably have to be implemented from scratch, as I think there is no package with that functionality. You also can't expect someone from StackOverflow to write all the code for you. This is not really a coding problem.